# Are the Piattino Sound Proofing Castor Cup really efficient and are there other equivalent solutions?

Tags: piano, practice, acoustics

I am improving my piano practice room and I found recently the Piattino Sound Proofing Castor Cup.

These work, as far as I understand, by absorbing vibration from the piano to the structures around and therefor avoiding structural transmission. I am trying to avoid noise from getting to my neighbours.

I have already put a couple of rugs under my piano, and I can still feel some vibration on the floor so I believe I can benefit from such a solution where vibration is absorbed.

In any case, how good are these? Are there equivalent solutions with a better cost?

Answer (score 1):

The only good soundproofing tools are  **mass** & **airgapping/vacuum**

This is a universal truth.

Anything else is a poor third place.

You can reduce vibration transmission through to the floor with dense foams, but their actual efficiency is remarkably low if you take air transmission into account too. A piano can transmit simply through the air to the floor, negating much of the effect any such damping may provide.

In short, unless you have a good 2 feet of solid concrete between you & your neighbours, no amount of sound damping is really going to make much difference.